# Find and delete listeners

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

I am trying to devise a unit test for a MATLAB app that can run either in windowed or headless mode. The test runs through the program in headless mode and tries to detect if any windows get opened during process.

My thought on this was to attach a listener to the [`groot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/groot.html) property `CurrentFigure`, and write a `PostSet` callback that increments a counter that keeps track of how many windows get opened. At the end the test then makes sure that the value is 0. For the record, this doesn't seem to work. Even though I have `ShowHiddenHandles` to `'on'`, it does not seem to catch modal windows. However, that is not my question.

My question is, I had an error in the test code between the place where I created the listener and the place where I `delete` it. Now, there is a listener attached to `groot`, but the listener handle variable is cleared, so I get really weird behavior every time I try to open a window. The test object opens back up and then throws an error at the listener callback.

How can I find and delete the listener attached to `groot` now that all original references to it have been removed from the workspace? So far the only method that works is to restart MATLAB, but that seems like an inefficient debugging method.

---

To reproduce the error, create the following test class:

```
classdef MCVtest < matlab.unittest.TestCase
    % Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example

    properties
        numOfFiguresCreated = 0;
    end

    methods
        function figureCreatedListener(testCase)
            testCase.numOfFiguresCreated = testCase.numOfFiguresCreated + 1;
        end
    end

    methods (Test)
        function testFiles(testCase)
            %Create Listener for this particular input file.
            listener = addlistener(groot, 'CurrentFigure', 'PostSet', @testCase.figureCreatedListener); %#ok<NASGU>

            error('Well, this sucks...')

            % delete Listener for this input file
            delete(listener) %#ok<UNRCH>

            % Verify That no graphics objects were created at all.
            testCase.verifyEqual(testCase.numOfFiguresCreated, 0);

        end
    end

end
```

From the command line:

```
>> suite = matlab.unittest.TestSuite.fromClass(?MCVtest)
>> results = suite.run
```

After the error:

```
>> figure
Error using MCVtest/figureCreatedListener
Too many input arguments.

Error in MCVtest>@(varargin)testCase.figureCreatedListener(varargin{:}) (line 17)
            listener = addlistener(groot, 'CurrentFigure', 'PostSet', @testCase.figureCreatedListener); %#ok<NASGU>
```

Of course, `listener` no longer exists, so I can't delete it. I've tried `clear`, `clear all`, and `clear classes`, in that order, and the listener still persists. The only way to clear it (so far as I've found) is to restart MATLAB.

Comment: Please see: [mcve]. I cannot reproduce this issue, once the listener goes out of scope the `PostSet` callback is no longer fired.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but clearing a listener does not remove it as you found out.  You have to call delete on the listener object (ex.  listObj = addlistener(...)  then later  delete(listObj))   https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/listener-lifecycle.html

Comment: Adding the unit-testing tag so that @AndyCampbell sees this question - he's the man you need here...

Comment: @AeroEngy that's only half true, there are two types of listeners.

Comment: @excaza example added.

Comment: @AeroEngy The issue is that my original code threw an error before it got to the `delete` part, so I'm wondering what to do to clean things up.

Comment: If you're able to use `listener` instead of `addlistener` then they're not going to be bound to the object and will clear when out of scope.

Comment: That works, although since the original version of the code that I found this in was written by one of my coworkers, I'd still like to know if there's a way to recover from `addlistener` in case I run into it again in the future.

Comment: That's fair. I misread the question @excaza. Will remove my answer and responses. I do think in general they should avoid using addlistener to avoid having this state to cleanup as you've pointed out.

Comment: You may be aware of this, but that _particular_ error message isn't about listener lifecycle, its pointing to a problem in the signature of your function. The callback needs to accept two input arguments. However I realize you are asking more about the fact that the listener executed after the test was long gone after the error. Even if the signature was right you would have gotten an error because the testCase would have been deleted.

The crux of the problem is that you are storing the listener on a global object. Globals always make things hard and are worth avoiding if possible.

Comment: https://blogs.mathworks.com/developer/2015/02/10/global/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to find the listeners by accessing the undocumented `'AutoListeners__'` property of the `Root` (or any other graphics) object, which contains a cell array of the listeners.

For example:

```
a = addlistener(groot, 'CurrentFigure', 'PostSet', @(s,e)disp('hi'));
tmp = groot;
listeners = tmp.AutoListeners__;
```

Which gives us:

```
>> a == listeners{1}

ans =

  logical

   1
```

So we can do something like:

```
for ii = 1:numel(listeners)
    delete(listeners{ii});
end
```

To remove all of the dangling listeners.

Note that `AutoListeners__` does not exist if there are no listeners for the object.

---

Also note that MATLAB has [2 different listener implementations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/events-and-listeners-syntax-and-techniques.html#brqorok): [`addlistener`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.addlistener.html), which binds the listener to the object and is removed when the *object* goes out of scope, and [`listener`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.listener.html), which us unbound and will be removed when the *listener* goes out of scope.

By utilizing `listener` instead of `addlistener` in your unit testing, you can avoid having dangling listeners if your cleanup is not run for whatever reason, in this case due to an error.

Comment: I don't think you've properly read the question. Having a reference to the listener isn't the issue, he already has that with `addlistener`. The problem is that, in an error condition, the handle to the listener object goes out of scope but the behavior is still in place because it is bound to the `groot` object. The only reason `AutoListeners__` is necessary is because the reference is lost. The behavior of `proplistener` is no different than `listener`.

Comment: Agree, my mistake. Sorry for correcting you when in fact it was me who had not read the question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using a lower level interface to create and manage your listeners so that you never have to resolve this stranded listener state problem again. You can tie the only reference to the listener to the function or object lifecycle scope that you want, so that you don't have to explictly delete listeners and can instead rely on reference counting to delete the listener once the last reference is destroyed.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/event.listener.html

or

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/event.proplistener.html

These interfaces allow you to receive the listener object as a LHS argument after creation. You can then decide whether to store the listener so that you can manage its lifecycle as you want to.

If you use this interface, you may be able to avoid using delete explicitly because you can tie the lifetime of the one and only listener handle to the scope in which you want it to exist.

So, concretely, in the same example:

```
lsnr = event.proplistener(groot,findprop(groot,'CurrentFigure'),'PostSet',@(hobj,evt) disp('fire'));
```

When lsnr falls out of scope, the last reference to the listener object will be lost and lsnr will be deleted automatically. Of course, you can also call delete explicitly.

Comment: Not my day, you were absolutely correct in your answer and that my code needing editing as written. You provided the right answer, which I have upvoted. Hopueflly we've cleared up my mistake.